# ObjC: in init can I do self = [self initWithMyGenericMethod]?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my class I have a generic initializer:

```
- (id)initWithSettings:(MySettings *)settings
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
     /// ...
    }
    return self;
}
```

And it has another initialiser with fixed setting

```
- (id)initWithSettingsForCaseA
{
    return [self initWithSettings:[MySettings genericSettings]];
}
```

Can I do this?

Comment: That's all good, but if `initWithSettingsForCaseA` is the default initializer and if you will not implement `init` then you might as well rename `initWithSettingsForCaseA` to `init`. Less chances for your initializer not getting called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can!

This is actually a good practice.

initWithSettings: is called the "designated initializer". There's no programmatic way of defining the designated initializer. This is more of a design pattern/best practice.

Take for instance the designated initializer for a UIViewController, initWithNibName:bundle:..you can still call plain ol' init and everything will work just fine as long as your nib is named the same as your view controller subclass. UIViewController simply calls its designated initializer and passes nil for both parameters.

You're essentially doing the same thing!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I thought `self = [super init]` will create `self` which we need to check if it is not nil, so in that case, `self = [self initWithSomething]`, the `self` inside bracket is not initialized yet.

Comment: The object is created during the `alloc`, not the `init`.  The `init` methods simply set the initial state of the already created object.

Comment: self isn't initialized yet, until you call [super init], which returns an initialized instance of your class. If your class inherits from a UIKit/Foundation class, you can pretty much rest assured that [super init] will return a valid instance. [self initWithSettings:] will return an initialized instance, so returning that from initWithSettingsForCaseA is perfectly valid

Comment: @jmstone But then why do you still need to check `if (self) {}`? So there is a chance that self can be nil? If so (ie after `self=[super init]`), then how can I make sure `self` inside bracket of `self = [self initWithSettings:...]` is not nil?

Comment: You check if self isn't nil out of a)best practice and b)for safety. Assuming your class inherits from NSObject, you don't need to worry about the case where self is nil from [super init]. If that ever happens, we're all in trouble. You would need to check if you were inheriting from a class that did some whacky initialization. If for some reason that failed and the object wasn't properly initialized, the run time will surely let you know, and you can go back and fix the offending code